# How to deeply analyze Java switches over enumerations with SonarQube

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement, sonarqube

To me, the following Java code is perfectly valid, good style:

```
enum Side { LEFT, RIGHT };
...
Side side = ...;
switch (side) {
case LEFT:
    // do something
    break;
case RIGHT:
    // do something
    break;
}
```

For SonarQube’s rule `SwitchLastCaseIsDefaultCheck`, this is not good enough, it wants a default case. Now here, a default case is superfluous, since the enumeration is covered completely.

For enumerations, I would like to see a test that checks whether the enumeration is completely covered and complain if it is not covered *and* has no default case (Eclipse can do that). Either should be fine. In fact, completely covering an enumeration allows for a compile-time warning later when the enumeration is extended, while giving a default case will fail only at run-time.

Optionally, both completely covering the enumeration and giving a default case could trigger a warning for unreachable code.

Comment: And what is the exact question here ?

Comment: Why don't you implement command pattern in your enum and do the enum-specific code there? That way you would not need a switch statement at all and nothing bad happens if someone is extending that enum (with maybe `UP` or `DOWN`) but forgets to update that switch (which is exactly why sonar warns about that if you have that rule active).

Comment: @Julien: The question is ‘How to deeply analyze Java switches over enumerations with SonarQube?’

Comment: @Matthias: Putting the code in the enumeration neatly solves the problem that adding an enumeration constant should always also add code handling it. However, it is not always feasible to do so, and so the poblem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, three years after asking the question I find that `squid:SwitchLastCaseIsDefaultCheck` now checks for complete coverage of an `enum`. Probably has for some time now, at least for 4.4.0.8066 of the Java plugin from Sonarqube I can confirm that. And that’s a very satisfactory answer for me.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest it is good practice to always include a default case which throws an appropriate `RuntimeException`. This way, you guard against a future developer adding something to the `enum` and forgetting to update the `switch` statement.

Comment: This seems to be the suggestion that Sonar implies. However, it does not guard me _statically_, at compile time. Why would I want a runtime exception when the issue can be statically determined even before starting the program?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is an IDE, it help you to develop the programs in a selected language here in your case it is JAVA, it doesn't do any thing which is not specified in language, so it is not the problem of eclipse, it is all about the specification of language.

Comment: No-one was suggesting a problem in Eclipse. On the contrary, I explicitly mentioned Eclipse as an example of how to correctly analyze the issue.